# Why is bookmarkItem.url returning as undefined while bookmarkItem.id is working fine?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a small browser extension (currently targeted for Firefox using the WebExtensions API. The first step was to have it strip ?utm_source=... from a url whenever a new bookmark was added. This works.

```
function bookmarkCreated(id, bookmarkInfo) {
    console.log(`Bookmark ID: ${id}`);
    console.log(`Bookmark URL: ${bookmarkInfo.url}`);
    currentURL = bookmarkInfo.url;

    var strippedURL = currentURL.replace(/\?utm_source=.*/, "");

    var newURL = browser.bookmarks.update(id, {
        url: strippedURL
    });
}
```

Now I'm working on adding functionality to iterate through all existing bookmarks and strip them of ?utm_source=... This is not working.

I used some [example code from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/getTree#Examples) that iterates through the bookmarks and outputs the values to the console. This code works fine:

```
function makeIndent(indentLength) {
  return ".".repeat(indentLength);
}

function logItems(bookmarkItem, indent) {
  if (bookmarkItem.url) {
    console.log(makeIndent(indent) + bookmarkItem.url);
  } else {
    console.log(makeIndent(indent) + "Folder");
    indent++;
  }
  if (bookmarkItem.children) {
    for (child of bookmarkItem.children) {
      logItems(child, indent);
    }
  }
  indent--;
}

function logTree(bookmarkItems) {
  logItems(bookmarkItems[0], 0);
}

function onRejected(error) {
  console.log(`An error: ${error}`);
}

var gettingTree = browser.bookmarks.getTree();
gettingTree.then(logTree, onRejected);`
```

I added within logItems above a call to bookmarkCreated (first snippet above) - thinking that this should update the url. It seems to pull the bookmarkItem.id fine, but gets the bookmarkItem.url as undefined.

```
if (bookmarkItem.url) {
  console.log(makeIndent(indent) + bookmarkItem.url);
  bookmarkCreated(bookmarkItem.id, bookmarkItem.url);
} else {
  console.log(makeIndent(indent) + "Folder");
  indent++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting a bookmarkItem as your second paramater, but there is url instead.
Either change signature of bookmarkCreated or change second paramater to bookmarkItem.

Comment: Thanks baklazan, that was it!